# ImageMagick requirement for Paperclip plugin

Tags: mac, installation, images, ruby, imagemagick

The Ruby on Rails paperclip plugin says that I need to install ImageMagick in order to use Paperclip. I'm typically really bad at getting things installed and running, so I was wondering if anyone could explain to me the exact specific steps I should take to get it installed and communicating with Paperclip.

I'm using Ruby on Rails on Mac OSX.

UPDATE:

I've already downloaded ImageMagick and extracted its contents. Now I need to make it communicate with Paperclip. However, I'm not sure if I've completely set up ImageMagick because the command `which convert` doesn't return anything...

Could anyone please help? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have extracted the contents of the downloaded ImageMagick, but you likely did not install it. The easiest way to get open-source software installed on OS X is through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Once you install the MacPorts package, it will allow you to install its software *ports* in `/opt/local`. You can install ImageMagick using:

```
sudo port install imagemagick
```

It will take care of any dependencies required. You can also [use MacPorts to install Ruby on Rails](http://www.davesouth.org/stories/install-ruby-on-rails-using-macports). Hopefully this helps. The key goal I'm trying the relate is to use a software package manager that takes care of dependencies and updates for you with only a few tools you need to learn.

Comment: i installed MacPorts, but when I run `sudo port install ImageMagick` I get `sudo: port: command not found`

Comment: Check your `~/.profile`. The MacPorts installer usually prepends `/opt/local/bin` to `$PATH`. If so, try `echo $PATH` and see if it's prepended. If it shows in `~/.profile` but not in `echo $PATH`, re-open your terminal or run `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: Yea the problem was that since I installed Macports with my terminal open, I needed to re-open my terminal :)

Comment: After ImageMagick is installed, what should I do from there? The instructions on the site are rather confusing for me.

Comment: My thought is that you're exactly where you wanted to be at the start of your question. Running `which convert` should now return `/opt/local/bin/convert`. I would assume Paperclip would work now. However, I don't have much experience using Ruby. If you would like to go ahead and use MacPorts to install Ruby on Rails, you would be better off removing the one you have installed now before proceeding (unless it's the system one).

Answer (score 1):

I would better suggest to use [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) for installation on Mac rather than ports and then [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) (ruby enVironment manager) to install various rubies and manage gems.